# Why does enumerate NOT give me an index error?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate

Python does not give me an index error with this for loop:

```
s = ['one', 'two']

for index, char in enumerate(s):
    if s[index - 1] != ' ' or s[index + 1212] != ' ':
        pass
```

but with the conditions swapped it does give me an index error:

```
s = ['one', 'two']

for index, char in enumerate(s):
    if s[index + 1212] != ' ' or s[index - 1] != ' ':
        pass
```

Someone care to explain?

Comment: It's because of [short-circuit evaluation](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-language/intermediate-python/short-circuit-evaluation/)

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, including Python, boolean expressions are evaluated one part at a time, and the evaluation stops as soon as one of the parts is false. This is called "[short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)" or "minimal evaluation".

In your case, if `s[index - 1] != ' '` is false, then `s[index + 1212] != ' '` won't be evaluated at all, which in turn won't raise an error.